# Python twisted ImportError: cannot import name unicode

Tags: python, dependencies, twisted

Something wrong with my twisted dependencies, it worked and now i`m getting this error while importing protocol and reactor:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov 25 2014, 09:23:41)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nick/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from twisted.python import compat
  File "/home/nick/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/compat.py", line 23, in <module>
    import sys, string, socket, struct
  File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
  File "/home/nick/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 17, in <module>
    from twisted.python import log, failure, components
  File "/home/nick/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 19, in <module>
    from twisted.python.compat import unicode, _PY3
ImportError: cannot import name unicode
```

Comment: Can you import twisted.python.compat? If so, does it has a function or a class or a module called unicode?

Comment: The line causing the exception has been removed from twisted. You should see if it works when you update twisted to a more recent version.

Comment: It's lasted twisted 15, I,m confused, cause reinstall via pip does not help...

Comment: You seem to have a virtualenv.  You should probably delete it and create a brand new one instead of trying to upgrade it in-place.  Upgrades are hard; fresh, clean installs are pretty well-tested and easier to debug.

Comment: look, a cant understand why now it works in python console and dont work in script. I dont use virtualenv

Comment: Please explain how you set up this environment, exactly how you're running your code, and exactly how you're starting your interactive interpreter. There is no standard installation mechanism I'm aware of that would put files into `/home/nick/env/env/lib`, so if you're not using `virtualenv` to create that environment then we can't even guess at what is happening.

Comment: Also, while @Jean-PaulCalderone's advice is good (recreating environments fresh is a good step if things get mysteriously messed up) it *should* be possible to upgrade Twisted in-place with a tool like `pip.

Comment: Pip install twisted.... It worked well sometime and now I got this error. After that I installed virtualenv, inside installed twisted via pip. And now inside virtualenv twisted works only inside python console, but running python script.py cause error...

Comment: Note Glyph's request: "Please explain how you set up this environment, exactly how you're running your code, and exactly how you're starting your interactive interpreter."  Without this information all anyone can do is make guesses about what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s how Python searching and including libs. In my directory was file called socket.py
In my script i included "from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol"
Twisted lib loads socket lib - so my socket.py overheads standart lib.
So, be carefully with naming scripts...

Also if you load python console, current directory includes as lib searching path.